# Rails: submitting form in form's path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I've got a form that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for edit_user_path(SOMETHING) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :client_code_suggest %>
<% end %>
```

How can I submit `SOMETHING` typed in the form through the path? Probably need a new controller method because that'd find user by `ID` and not `client_code`, but I'm not sure how to implement that in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in a Rails app you would have something like `form_for @user`, which knows to submit the form to either `users_path` (if `@user` is not persisted) or `user_path(@user)` (if `@user` is persisted).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

You can overwrite the URL it submits to (if you need to) with the `url` option, eg. `form_for @user, url: some_other_path`

Comment: How then would I declare `@user` in the controller then if I'm trying to search existing users?

Comment: you wouldn't if you were trying to search users, you also wouldn't use `form_for`, because you don't have a form for anything. You'd likely just use a standard Rails `form_tag`.

Comment: Yeah, that's cool. I still need to pass whatever's in the `text_field_tag` to the method though, right?

Comment: if you want to access it in the controller, sure - add a submit button to the form, point the form to an index action or a search action or something like that, then implement the searching.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Cheers.